# Adding a new group to an SSRS tablix with existing groups?

Tags: grouping, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have an existing report that has three levels of grouping. I'm being asked to add a fourth level outside the current levels (to the left in the report). I can't seem to get the new group to look like or behave like the original groups that SSRS built for me when I constructed the report.

The original report looks like:
[image]

I group on AppOwner, a computed AppName and RepositoryName. The detail row is below that. You can see the grouping outlining showing each group containing its group "header" and the child rows below it. Here's the Row Grouping pane:

[image]

I'm trying to add a new Company group outside the AppOwner group. It needs to encompass all the rows below it and it needs to reside in its own row so I can put some expressions in the columns. When I drag-drop Company from Report Data to the Grouping Pane it adds a column with a merged cell it won't allow me to split that shows all the child group rows when I preview it even though I've set the AppOwner group to Hide and toggle on Company. Here's the designer view:

[image]

And here's how it renders:

[image]

I don't want the big column for Company that spans all the child rows, I want Company on its own row like the other groups so that when I initially open the report all I see is the Company rows.

I've tried every solution I can find via Google and searching here on SO. The only thing close I've found here is someone who edited the base XML for the report. That can't be the best answer...

Comment: Right click the `AppOwner` cell and select "Insert Row -> Outside Group-Above" This will insert a blank row inside of the the `Company` group, but above the `AppOwner` group.  You can then delete the `Company` column (this will **NOT** delete your `Company` group) and merge all of the cells on the newly created row.

Comment: @Kidiskidvogingogin - that worked perfectly. Can you post it as an Answer so I can acknowledge it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add the row inside of the `Company` group but above the `AppOwner` group you need to right click the `AppOwner` cell and select "Insert Row" -> "Outside Group - Above."  This will insert a blank row inside of the `Company` group, but above the `AppOwner` group.  If you wish to remove the `Company` column you can delete it (this will **NOT** delete the `Company` group). Then if you want the `Company` field to span all columns simply highlight the cells within the row, right click, and select "Merge Cells".

Comment: Thanks @Kidiskidvogingogin

Comment: @RichardSchaefer No problem.  Glad I could help.